# Android Studio downloading wrong gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just updated Android Studio to 3.6.1 (don't know from which version) to work on an old project (1,5 -2 years ago).
When I opened my project, it suggested to update the gradle to:

- Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.6.1
- Gradle Version: 5.6.4

But this will only work, when I manually download this gradle version and set "specified location" in the preferences.
If I use gradle-wrapper with:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

it always downloads gradle version 5.2.1 and I will get the error that it requires 5.6.4 but 5.2.1 is installed.

Any suggestions to look for? Total noob here, so please explain as simple as possible.

**Edit2:** these are the three files I'm working in. I messed around with it (cleaned, rebuilt, etc.) and then I'm getting this error with the settings from picture 4.
gradle wrapper properties:
[image: gradle wrapper properties]
build gradle Android:
[image: build gradle Android]

build gradle app:
[image: build gradle app]

settings not working:
[image: settings not working]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried going to the graddle files and updating it there?

Comment: I changed it in the gradle-wrapper file by hand  to 5.6.4 like it is doing it automatically. I also checked the other two files (for project and ???) and changed the plugin version to 3.6.1 in there by hand. Are there any more spots, that have to be changed? If I put in 3.4.0 with 5.2.1 it would work.

Comment: When you changed all of those things didn't android studio sync your project?

Comment: I think it is syncing (at least it is doing something) and brings up the same error. I can even push sync now or try again to start it manually, but the result is always the same. It downloads the 5.2.1

Comment: Try to clean and re-build the project

Comment: I tried clean project under the build menu, but all it gave me, was a duplicate of nearly every file in my project with a " 2" at the end of its name. Is there any other place, where you define wich version gets downloaded. Or does it depend on some other defined versions in the project?

Comment: Take a screenshot and send it to me please

Comment: I added the screenshots to the question.

Comment: I don't know man, I"m sorry :(
If you don't have many classes, try to start a new project and copy the code maybe?

Comment: I have the same issue in Android Studio 4.0. If I click Build > Clean Project, it starts downloading Gradle 5.2.1 for some reason. I'm using Gradle 6.4.1 and it works fine for running the app.